# VueJS Multiple Dropdowns - Rendered Options depends on first selected value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am facing some issues here trying to render a second select dropdown. I currently am fetching data with axios from an API. The options of the second select dropdown is depending on what is selected in the first dropdown.

The JSON looks like this:

```js
    {
    "citizens": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Boy1",
          "contact": [
            {
              "id": "1",
              "name": "Mother1"
            },
            {
              "id": "2",
              "name": "Father1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Boy2",
          "contact": [
            {
              "id": "1",
              "name": "Mother2"
            },
            {
              "id": "2",
              "name": "Father2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
    }
```

Based on the JSON, In the first select dropdown, I am rendering **correctly** {{citizen.name}}, which in this case will be: **Boy1** and **Boy2**.

But, in the second dropdown, I want to render the **citizen.contact.name** available in the first selected dropdown (v-model). For example, I choose Boy1, the second dropdown should have Mother1 and Father1. If I select Boy2, then it should be Mother2 and Father2.

```js
    <select v-model="selectOne">
    <option v-for="citizen of citizens" :key="citizen.id">{{citizen.name}}</option>
    </select>
    
    <select v-model="selectTwo">
    <option>Mother1</option>
    <option>Father1</option>
    </select>
```

I am returning data() for citizens: [] and selectOne: "". I tried adding v-models on both select tags (selectOne and selectTwo) and a computed property:

```js
    computed: {
        selectTwo() {
          return console.log(this.selectOne);
        },
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind the whole selected `citizen` from your select, for example called `selected`. Use the value of the whole `citizen` object, then you can in your second select iterate through `selected.contact`:

```html
<select v-model="selected">
  <option :value="citizen" v-for="citizen of citizens" :key="citizen.id">{{citizen.name}}</option>
</select>

<!-- Maybe need a v-model here too so you can keep track of choice -->
<select v-model="selectedContact">
  <option v-for="contact of selected.contact" :key="contact.id">{{contact.name}}</option>
</select>
```

and to the script, of course add `selected` (and `selectedContact`) as variable.

If you want to keep your first select as a string and not bind the whole object, you can as you attempted use a computed property like:

```html
contacts() {
  return this.selected ? this.citizens.find(x => x.name === this.selected).contact : []
}
```

and template:

```html
<select v-model="selected">
  <option v-for="citizen of citizens" :key="citizen.id">{{citizen.name}}</option>
</select>

<select v-model="selectedContact">
  <option v-for="contact of contacts" :key="contact.id">{{contact.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Holy crab, many thanks for the fas reply!! its always easier than I imagine... by the way, another quick one. In the returned data(), I have added **selected: "Boy1"**, why is it not showing as default? @ajt82

Comment: I updated my answer with the option to use a computed property. The reason for the first part of the answer and "boy1" not being selected, is that we are binding the whole object, not the string. You would need to make a reference to that object. But if you want to go with the second part of the answer, youe `selected: "Boy1"` will work, as we are using a string.

Comment: You are very welcome,glad I could help, have a good weekend and happy coding! :)